# How can i disable the browser’s back functionality after logout in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session, browser-cache, session-timeout

I want to disable the browser's back button after log out.

I have already set session `["session-id"]` to null on log out event.

But when I am pressing <kbd>back</kbd> button of the browser :

**It will redirect me to that secure page from which I've already log out.**

Please Give me any solution about this problem

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930487/how-to-prevent-browser-back-button-after-logout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below Javascript code may help you...

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > 
    function preventBack(){window.history.forward();} 
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0); 
    window.onunload=function(){null}; 
    </script>
```

use the code in a page where you don't want to go back...