# Home page still accessible after destroying session to logout

Tags: node.js, express, session

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.session.adminloggedIn){
    productHelpers.getAllProducts().then((products)=>{
      res.render('admin/view-products',{admin:true,products})
    })
  }else{
    res.redirect('admin/admin-login')
  }
});


router.get('/admin-login',(req,res)=>{
  if(req.session.adminloggedIn){
    res.redirect('/admin') 
  }else{
    res.render('admin/admin-login',{loginErr:req.session.adminloginErr,admin:true})
  }
})

router.post('/admin-login',(req,res)=>{
  //console.log(req.body)
  productHelpers.AdminLogin(req.body).then((response)=>{
    console.log(response)
    if(response.status){
      req.session.admin=response.admin
      req.session.adminloggedIn=true;
      res.redirect('/admin')
    }else{
      req.session.adminloginErr="invalid username or password"
      res.redirect('/admin/admin-login')
    }
  })
})


router.get('/logout',(req,res)=>{
  req.session.admin=null
  req.session.adminloggedIn=false
  res.redirect('/admin/admin-login')
})
```

these are the routes for my project for home page,logging in and logging out respectively,

The code works fine but the issue is after  logging out when i press the back button in the browser,it redirects back to the home page,the home page is usually only accessible when logged in.

The session is destroyed,but the home page is still accessible when going back and only when it is refreshed it is asked to log in

I added the if clause to check the session when accessing the home page but again  it only works after refreshing

please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent browser back button after logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930487/how-to-prevent-browser-back-button-after-logout)